# Developing and deploying code using a trunk-based model in Salesforce

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, feature-management

Disclaimer: I am not a Salesforce developer. I am trying to understand how to develop and deliver "features" incrementally to a production environment using trunk-based development.

Trunk based development is considered a best practice when developing software. Doing so would allow in-progress features to be checked into a shared branch (such as `trunk` or `main line`) while still allowing that branch to be deployed to production at any time. To achieve this goal, one option I'd like to understand more about is applying feature toggles to Apex code.

I have not found much documentation on the Salesforce site describing how you can develop a feature incrementally and have it toggled off in production and on in non prod. (For example a simple conditional that can be set via environment config.)

I'm not familiar with how features work with the database models and metadata etc. I'm trying to understand if this approach is something that I can recommend to a team because it can work with most (all) of the Salesforce development that can be applied.

I came across https://github.com/rocnick/Togglr so it seems someone has had a crack at it, but I'd like to know if there is more native support for this or does this type of behaviour need to be customised to achieve.

I understand that there may be limitations to Salesforce development and I don't want to go against the grain with what they recommend so I'm also not looking to pervert the laws of Salesforce either.

Comment: edited your post to clarify for others what you mean by trunk-based dev. Feel free to edit it more to explain further.

Answer (score 0):

There are two levels of features: system-context and user-context.  An example of the former would be a trigger or nightly batch process.  The latter could be a page, flow or object.

For system-context, Custom Metadata flags could be used to enable or disable a trigger or other system-level automations.

But for access to user-based features, it's best to use the Profiles feature.  Salesforce has a robust security model, so enabling a page, object or field within a security profile is all that is needed in order to grant/disable access.

From a code repo perspective, you wouldn't merge a feature into the production branch until it is final.  But if you need, for example, the base objects to exist in production before the custom pages are ready, you could deploy those objects and just not enable them in the users' profiles.  It would be like the objects didn't exist.

But the best practice would be not to deploy "half baked" features and then try to hide them.  Best to just keep them out of the main branch.

Comment: `best practice would be not to deploy "half baked" features` - Could you elaborate on this? Is this part of the SF DX recommendations or just an opinion based on experience? Just trying to understand the limitations of why this may be true relating to the way SF works.

Comment: This is opinion based on experience.  The whole point of the branching model in repos like SVN and GIT is to keep things aside until it's release time.  It's certainly possible to merge incrementally into the main branch and deploy.  And for very large projects, you might need to do this to avoid conflicts.  But there's a lot of overhead with ensuring that the hidden features are non-impactful...

Comment: `The whole point of the branching model in repos like SVN and GIT is to keep things aside until it's release time.` - I don't believe that's the purpose of branches, although yes people do use them for that reason.
`But there's a lot of overhead with ensuring that the hidden features are non-impactful.` - This is exactly what I'm trying to discover specifically relating to SalesForce technology. 

The reason to deploy incrementally is to de risk software delivery and increase the quality of what you develop. Bing bang deploys are riddled with issues this is what I want to avoid.

Comment: I guess it all comes down to what you are developing.  If the features are triggers or other system-context features, Custom Metadata Fields are a great feature for this purpose.  Triggers also have an "active" flag as well, so you could use that.  But isn't deploying a disabled feature and then turning them all on later also a sort of "big bang" release?  And there's overhead for tracking and activating the disabled triggers.  Instead, perhaps chop up the features into several very frequent live releases?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.
Big Bang releases mean drop a significant portion of the code into a production environment. Using feature flags allows you to have early features in a non prod environment which are on, being tested and integrated with all the other production code.You can deploy more frequently never block other work and avoid any long lived branches that need days or weeks to merge. Tracking features can be a simple db table. Turning on features one by one allows for staggered controlled feature release and a simple easy rollback. You should give it a go :)